# Read the Ticket data from a text file

Tags: java

I need to store a list of information (Lotto Ticket information example Name, Address, Phone number and chosen number) in a *.txt* file and convert it into java and create the ticket object from this information.

Best way to do this, I found was was using a string[] splitter and pharses as needed

Comment: If data is received from the file (as you wrote), you can use `nextLine()` - it will be more useful.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Are the column headings actually in the text file? If yes, read (and discard) them with `input.nextLine();` before you start trying to read the "real" data.

Comment: You need to focus on one problem at a time - it appears you might have multiple bugs, and you should try to solve them one at a time instead of all at once, including asking a question about just one at a time (after diligent research on your own on each first).  For example, can you successfully handle a Ticket with just `name` and none of the rest of the fields yet?

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to separate values by comma "," and convert the file format to `CSV`. This will fix the multi-word values problem.

Then read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61143464/5533359) for the steps you should take.